# Owl Carousel not working in SharePoint 2010

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, owl-carousel

I am using owl carousel with prettyPhoto to show a slider in SharePoint site using a custi=om web part. The script works perfectly in HTML page.
But when I render the same script and code in SharePoint webpart, it doesn't work at all. All the pictures are showing as static and their is no movement neither navigation buttons showing correct style.

Comment: Have you tested in multiple browsers? SharePoint 2010 usually forces compatibility mode, which emulates IE 8.

Comment: @Thriggle their is no change, the pictures are started to slide but still all the pictures are showing simultaneously and causing to increase the width of web part zone.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. What I meant was: If your script won't work in IE 8, it won't work in SharePoint 2010. You said it "works perfectly in HTML page"... Did that page work even in Internet Explorer 8?

Comment: @Thriggle yeah I understand that part. Anyway It is working now. Thanks.